# Is it possible to find the prime factors of $89!+97$?

Tags: prime-factorization

According to Wolfram Alpha, this number is not prime, but it does not display prime factors of this number as it normally does for other numbers so I am not so sure about it.  Several other factorization calculators I tried also failed to find prime factors of this number.  The main question I want to ask is this: Is it possible to show (by hand or with the help of a machine) whether the number $89!+97$ is prime or not, and if not, can we find its prime factors?

Comment: [factordb](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=89%21%2B97)

Comment: With ECM or the quadratic sieve, you can find the factors , without great luck both methods need much computational effort.

Comment: You could show that this number is composite by hand in principle , but it would be an enormous task considering it has $137$ digits. Finding the prime factors is only possible with electronic help (by hand it would take extremely long).

Comment: Finally note that primality testing is (probably) much easier than factoring. The decision whether a number is prime is in fact in $P$ , whereas factoring probably not. RSA is based on the difficulty to do that.

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much.

Comment: Fermat's (litttle) Theorem says that if $p$ is prime and $(a,p)=1$, then $a^{p-1}  \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  So if you have a candidate $p$ and can find an $a$ where this fails, you know $p$ is not a prime.  I think $a=5$ will work to show your number is not a prime.  You still need a computer to help with the arithmetic, but there is a fast algorithm to compute a power modulo something, so that helps.